# scheme basic loop

Tags: function, loops, scheme

I'm trying to write a scheme func that behaves in a way similar to a loop.

(loop min max func)

This loop should perform the func between the range min and max (integers)

-- one of an example like this

```
(loop 3 6 (lambda (x) (display (* x x)) (newline)))

9
16
25
36
```

and I define the function as

```
( define ( loop min max fn)
    (cond
        ((>= max min) ( ( fn min ) ( loop (+ min 1 ) max fn)  ) )
    )
)
```

when I run the code I get the result then an error occur.
I couldn't handle this error.

```
(loop 3 6 (lambda (x) (display(* x x))(newline)))

9
16
25
36

Backtrace:
In standard input:
  41:  0* [loop 3 6 #<procedure #f (x)>]

In utku1.scheme:
   9:  1  (cond ((>= max min) ((fn min) (loop # max fn))))
  10:  2  [#<unspecified> ...
  10:  3*  [loop 4 6 #<procedure #f (x)>]
   9:  4   (cond ((>= max min) ((fn min) (loop # max fn))))
  10:  5   [#<unspecified> ...
  10:  6*   [loop 5 6 #<procedure #f (x)>]
   9:  7    (cond ((>= max min) ((fn min) (loop # max fn))))
  10:  8    [#<unspecified> ...
  10:  9*    [loop 6 6 #<procedure #f (x)>]
   9: 10     (cond ((>= max min) ((fn min) (loop # max fn))))
  10: 11     [#<unspecified> #<unspecified>]

**utku1.scheme:10:31: In expression `((fn min) (loop # max ...))`:
    utku1.scheme:10:31:Wrong type to apply: `#<unspecified>`
ABORT: (misc-error)**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each clause of a cond expression has the form (*cond expr1 expr2...*), but you've wrapped both expr1 and expr2 in parens when they should be separate.  The solution would be to either specify `begin` at the beginning: `((>= max min) (begin expr1 expr2))` or make the `begin` implicit: `((>= max min) expr1 expr2)`.

Alternatively, it might make more sense to use a `when` statement instead of a `cond`, since you only have one choice:

```
(define (loop min max fn)
  (when (>= max min)
    (fn min)
    (loop (+ min 1) max fn)))
```

Because both `cond` and `when` are macros that use `if`, both versions become

```
(define (loop min max fn)
  (if (>= max min)
    (begin (fn min) (loop (+ min 1) max fn))
    (void)))
```

anyways.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ( ( fn min ) ( loop (+ min 1 ) max fn) )
> ```

This is the problem. What you want this to do is to execute `(fn min)` and then `(loop (+ min 1 ) max fn)` afterwards. What it actually does do is, it executes `(fn min)`, then `(loop (+ min 1 ) max fn)` and then it tries to apply the result of `(fn min)` to the result of `(loop (+ min 1 ) max fn)`. Since the result of `(fn min)` is not a function, this is an error.

To get what you want, do `( begin (fn min) (loop (+ min 1) max fn) )`. `begin` allows you to execute multiple expressions after one another.